# А как вы выводите всплывающие подсказки из php кода?

Tags: php, html

А как вы выводите всплывающие подсказки из php кода?
Была идея оставить внутри страницы div c пустой переменной php по середине экрана и при необходимости его заполнять информацией. но данный способ мне показался не красивым.
Мне нужно что бы при входе в панель управление, бац и всплывающее сообщение об успехе/не успехе.
Как вы бы решили данную задачу?

Comment: Сообщение о неправильном логине/пароле я бы оформил div большим и красным, чтобы бросался в глаза.  
Всплывающие подсказки оформил бы абсолютно позиционированным div, который показывал бы либо по координатам клика, либо относительно элемента к которому относиться подсказка.  
Хочу заметить, что всплывающая подсказка и всплывающее сообщение это две разные вещи и используются в разных целях. Уточните, пожалуйста, чего именно Вы хотите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут конечно всё упрощено, но примерно так:

Html:

```
<div>
    <label for="login">Логин</label>
    <input id="login" type="text" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" />
</div>
<div id="alert"></div>
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $.post('ajax/login.php', 
           { login: $('#login').val() }
            function(data) {
                if(data.success) 
                    $('#alert').html('Авторизован!').show();
                else
                    $('#alert').html('Ошибка в логине!').show();
            })
    .error(function() { alert("Не возможно связаться с сервером"); });

    );   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

А когда антивирус/броузер "говорит": заблокировано всплывающее окно? Выводите лучше на странице авторизации надпись/рисунок. (Не путайте подсказки и всплывающие окна).